# extjs adding additional field to dynamic forms

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need to allow my users to submit multiple property addresses by clicking a button that will insert a fieldset with extra text fields. I can do this simply with form.insert(index, component); However, that index will change after the user adds an additional property. For example, the index to add the extra properties is after the 7th component, making the index 7. But when you insert it at 7, it's index is now 7 and the next property will be inserted above it. This effect is further compounded when you try to do this with contact emails and numbers in the same form. So my question is, how can I get the index of the component in the form that I wish to insert the extra fields after?

Answer (score 0):

```
fieldset.items.getCount()
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: i need to know at what index a certain component WITHING that form is at.

Comment: I guess you will have to go through them and compare itemId or something. There is nothing built-in I believe.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly straight forward, but not too bad either. take a look at the following code: the first part is the button handler to add a set of fields, the second is the actual function that creates the indexed fields.

```
    handler:function () {
        var parts = this.up('fieldset'),
        index = parts.query('fieldcontainer').length, //calculate existing Part line items
        fields = this.up('window').createPartFieldContainer(index);
        parts.add(fields);
    }



createPartFieldContainer:function (index) {
    index = index || 0;
    return {
        xtype:'fieldcontainer',
        items:[
            { 
                xtype:'textfield', fieldLabel:'Item',
                name:'lineItem[' + index + '].itemNumber', width:100,
                emptyText:'Part Number'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```